# How to identify tables in text file using php

Tags: php

I have a text file with some text and tables.
How to identify at which position the table has started???  using **PHP**.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any demo text file with starter code ?

Comment: To, Whom it may concern.

SR# PRCODE NAME OF THE PRODUCT      PACKING  ORD1
     --- ------ ------------------------ -------- ----
       1 037150 ADILIP 135 TAB           1X10       15
       2 037121 ARVAST  5 TAB.           1X10       15
       3 037122 ARVAST 10 TAB.           1X15       20
       4 037156 ARVAST A  75 TAB.        1X10       10
       5 037157 ARVAST A 150 TAB         1X10       10
       6 037162 ARVAST CF 10 TAB         1X10       10

Comment: any link available (like google drive)?

Comment: no link available it is just text file in local machine

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working on a text file it's important to measure size of each line.
For example in your case:

```
1 037150 ADILIP   135 TAB 1X10 15 
2 037121 ARVAST     5 TAB 1X10 15 
3 037122 ARVAST    10 TAB 1X15 20  
4 037156 ARVAST A  75 TAB 1X10 10 
5 037157 ARVAST A 150 TAB 1X10 10 
6 037162 ARVAST CF 10 TAB 1X10 10
```

Each line's length is equal to 36 and as i assume fields are organized on purpose (Each space or character describes something).

After understanding and analyzing file structure, you can start working on it.

```
$myFile = "file.txt";

$content = file($myFile);

$contentLength = count($content);
```

After that we should start "For Loop" and start importing data from file:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $contentLength; $i++)
{
   //and here you start importing field:
   //for exaple: as i understand, first field is id

   $myId = $content[$i][0];
   //and so on, you get each field's value

   //and after finishing that maybe input it into database or output in browser, that totally depends on your application
}
```